# How can i use _defaults function in custom module openerp

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I write custom module, but i have a problem with _defaults function.

When I install module, it throw out an error

> Indentation Error: unexpected indent for "_defaults = {".

```
medical_diagnostic_hypothesis.py

from openerp.osv import fields, orm


class MedicalDiagnostic_hypothesis(orm.Model):
    _name = 'medical.diagnostic_hypothesis'
    #_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char(size=256, string='Diagnostic ID', required=True),
        'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner',
                                        required=True ),
        'pathology_category_id': fields.many2one('medical.pathology.category',
                                         'Pathology',required=True ),
        'diagnostic': fields.char(size=256, string='Diagnostic'),
        'treatment_method': fields.char(size=256, string='Treatment Method'),
    }
    _defaults = {
                 }
```

[Server trace-back image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyRAN.png)

Comment: did you left the _defaults dict. intentionally empty?

Comment: a same problem when the _deaults function has content. thanks for your comments !.

Comment: it's a Indentation error, you need to check it. Indentation must be match.

Comment: Stackoverflow is _not_ a forum so do not add stuff like [resolved] or tags to your title. Also, read the [faq]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code. (make a proper Indentation)

*medical_diagnostic_hypothesis.py*

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm

class MedicalDiagnostic_hypothesis(orm.Model):
    _name = 'medical.diagnostic_hypothesis'
    #_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char(size=256, string='Diagnostic ID', required=True),
        'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner',
                                        required=True ),
        'pathology_category_id': fields.many2one('medical.pathology.category',
                                         'Pathology',required=True ),
        'diagnostic': fields.char(size=256, string='Diagnostic'),
        'treatment_method': fields.char(size=256, string='Treatment Method'),
    }

    _defaults = {
    }
```

For more about [indentation in python.](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html)